# How to stop timer in Text view?

Tags: swift, swiftui

It is possible to pass a date to `Text()` in SwiftUI, then format it as a timer using the `style` argument. However, a countdown like this never stops, it just keeps incrementing after zero. How to make it stop at 0?

```swift
func nextRollTime(in seconds: Int) -> Date {
    let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: seconds, to: Date())
    return date ?? Date()
}
```

Above is the function I use to start a countdown, then I pass it as follows:

`Text(nextRollTime(in: 20), style: .timer)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a demo of possible approach - as `.timer` run from now for ever (by design), the idea is to replace it with regular text once specified period is over.

Tested with Xcode 12b3 / iOS 14.

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoView: View {
    @State private var run = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if run {
                Text(nextRollTime(in: 10), style: .timer)
            } else {
                Text("0:00")
            }
        }
        .font(Font.system(.title, design: .monospaced))
        .onAppear {
            self.run = true
        }
    }

    func nextRollTime(in seconds: Int) -> Date {
        let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: seconds, to: Date())
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(seconds)) {
            self.run = false
        }
        return date ?? Date()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. Should have thought of the DQ approach.

Comment: Curious, your example works fine, but in my project it fails to update `Text()` properly, although time elapsed is correct. It directly jumps to the last a few seconds (with lag). Any ideas on how to debug this?

Answer (score 3):

##### iOS16+ / macOS 13+

`Text` now has a dedicated initializer for this,
[`init(timerInterval:pauseTime:countsDown:showsHours:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(timerinterval:pausetime:countsdown:showshours:)).

You may use it like this:

```swift
let date = Date()
Text(timerInterval: date...date.addingTimeInterval(9), countsDown: true)
```