# Capturing remaining time in modifier .addingTimeInterval

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have discovered a modifier of Date that works great for counting down the time, which is a modifier named .addingTimeInterval.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let IntervalInSeconds = 10800.0  // 3 hours

    var body: some View {
 
        Text(Date().addingTimeInterval(IntervalInSeconds), style: .timer)
            .font(.custom("Arial", fixedSize: 75))
    }
}
```

The above is clean and simple and will display a countdown timer for the number of seconds specified, formatting it by hours, minutes, and seconds. It saves a lot of time having to write my own code to do this.

My goal is to monitor the time remaining on the countdown timer and when it reaches zero, execute a function that will play a sound and update one of the views.  The current implementation above counts down to zero but then begins to count up again.  I have tried using @State vars, tried to create a computed var, but because it is a modifier, I have not been able to capture the remaining time.

My question is, does anyone know if there is any way to capture the seconds remaining from this modifier, or am I going to have to write my own routine to do that?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Next should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/63425455/12299030.

Comment: With a couple of modifications for my specifics in the app, it worked great.  Thank you for the help!