# Observe if my value reached zero in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, date, swiftui, observable

Hey I am working on a timer inside of SwiftUI.
Currently I am using this variable here:

```
@State var timeRemaining: Date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 30)
```

and I display it inside this Text:

```
Text(timeRemaining, style: .relative).foregroundColor(.white)
```

**The problem:** If the counter reaches zero it starts counting up again from 0 to ∞.
So I need to detect when it reaches 0 so I can make it stay 0 right ?
At least that is what I thought of. I have read something about observables inside of Swift
where it can track if a value changed, but I did not figure out on how to achieve this in my
case. Any ideas ?

Comment: [This](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-a-timer-with-swiftui) might help

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63425455/12299030?